# Get Heroku release version from within Python app

Tags: python, heroku

How can I get the Heroku release number from within a Python app (example: `v274`)?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792716/reflecting-heroku-push-version-within-the-app), but was specifically for Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by enabling the [Heroku Labs Dyno Metadata](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata) feature, in which case your python app will be able to access a HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION env var.

Another way to do this would be by querying [Dyno Info from the Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-info). Inside the Dyno info you have release.version.